# CSS display none for class name when alone

Tags: html, css

I want to set the display option to none for a css class when it is alone but it also hides the element when it is used with another class.

so here is how the html looks like when I want to show the biography class:

```
<div class="user biography">
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

and here I want the biography class to be set to `display:none` when it is alone (not with user class):

```
<div class="biography">
  <p>should hide</p>
</div>
```

but if I do :

```
.biography{
  display: none;
}
```

it hides the biography class in both cases. How can I hide it when it is alone and not with user class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) `[class='biography']` and this will match all elements that have class with exact value of `biography`

```css
[class='biography'] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="user biography">
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
<div class="biography">
  <p>should hide</p>
</div>
```

Comment: awesome :) is this cross browser compatible?

Comment: Sure, you can see browser compatibility table at end of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 3):

You can use the attribute selector to see if the class matches that name exactly

```
[class="biography"] {
  display: none;
}
```

Only elements with `class="biography"` will be matched.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `:not` pseudoselector:

```
.biography:not(.user){
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to add a second class, and only apply display:none when both classes are present:

```
<div class="user biography">
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
<div class="biography hidden">
  <p>should hide</p>
</div>
<style>
.biography.hidden {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.biography {
    display: none;
}

.biography.user {
    display: block; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use `disply:none` by default and `display:block` when the element is inside or with a class. So, you can do this:

```css
.user.biography {
  display: block;
}

.biography {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="user biography">
  <p>Content</p>
</div>



<div class="biography">
  <p>should hide</p>
</div>
```